# Table - Increasing the space between header and first row

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, repeater

I want to increase the space between the header row and the first row in the table. How do I do this?

I have the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" >
   <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="width:100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr align="left">
                        <th style="width:15%">
                            Column 1  
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:15%">
                            Column 2
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:15%">
                            Column 3
                        </th>                            
                     </tr>
                </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <tbody style="padding-top: 50px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                   </tr>                        
                </tbody>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            <tr style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                <td colspan="7" style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 20px;">
                    <hr style="width:100%" /></td>
            </tr>
        </SeparatorTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

As you can see I have added    `<style="padding-top: 50px;">`
to the table body but this doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure but maybe:

```
thead{padding-bottom:2em;}
```

Would give you the result you want.

Comment: You cannot apply padding to the `thead` element, give it a test, nothing will happen, just as you can't pad `tr` or `tbody`

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way would be to add padding to the bottom of the `<th>` elements

```
<th style="width:15% padding-bottom: 50px">
     Column 1  
</th>
<th style="width:15% padding-bottom: 50px">
     Column 2
</th>
<th style="width:15%; padding-bottom: 50px">
     Column 3
</th>
```

Note: this is good for testing purposes but this really should be done in a stylesheet and not directly in the html.

```
th {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```